# How to use Flask to get the Python return value in typescript

Tags: typescript

I write a Flask router in Python，but does not know how to get it's return value in
typescript file

```
from tushareController import binding
from flask import Flask, request, make_response, redirect, render_template, url_for

import js
import pandas
import numpy

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/pycontroller/<exchange>', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def getJsonData(exchange):
  df = binding(exchange)
  json = df.to_json()

  return json

if __name__ == '__main__':
  app.run(
    host='0.0.0.0',
    port=5000,
    debug=True
  )
```

I don't know how to get back-end data through front-end code

Comment: Just check the fetch function of typescript...